# MySQL "Not Equal" Operator is Valid, but not Working Properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL Statement to help find similar bands for a recommendation list. It does what I want, but one small thing. It won't block bands that are already favorited from being queried.

Here is the statement:

```
foreach ($recomBands as $val) {
    $genres[] = "'%".$val."%'";
}
$string = implode(' OR `genre` LIKE ', $genres);

foreach ($favedBands as $value) {
    $bands[] = "'" . sanitize($value) . "'";
}
$bandString = implode(' OR `band_name` != ', $bands);

$sql = "SELECT `band_name`, `band_id` FROM `song_genres` WHERE `band_name` != {$bandString} AND `genre` LIKE {$string}";

// QUERY CODE AND WHAT NOT GOES HERE. ALL WORKING FINE
```

That echos out:

```
 SELECT `band_name`, `band_id` FROM `song_genres` WHERE `band_name` != 'Bears and Company' AND `genre` LIKE '%Indie Rock%' OR `genre` LIKE '%Progressive Rock%' OR `genre` LIKE '%Alternative Rock%' OR `genre` LIKE '%Indie Folk%'
```

It is a valid query (albeit not what most people would do exactly, but that's beside the point). The output array shows

```
array(17) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "Henry's Funeral Shoe"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "Bears and Company"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "Bears and Company"
// AND A LIKE 15 MORE OF BEARS AND COMPANY
```

The goal is to compare all genres found within a band and group them toward other bands with genres like that and then sort them. That all works fine, but the bands that I want out of the query still show up. Why?

P.S. I have other dummy accounts for testing with multiple bands, genres, etc in random orders.

Comment: In stead of != use NOT LIKE...and that will resolve your problem I guess.

               ( WHERE `band_name` NOT LIKE '%Bears and Company%' AND )

Comment: It doesn't work. Not to mention, it would have to be exact. If another band had the word Company in it (quite common actually), they probably won't get selected. It needs to be a perfect match.

Comment: There is one more type which is: `NOT (band_name = 'Bears and Company')` and if it is a perfect match then: `Strcmp(band_name, 'Bears and Company') <> 0` give these a try may be this helps

Comment: @Deep Still not working. This is really frustrating. I feel it shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

Not equals in SQL is `<>`.

So change to

```
$bandString = implode(' OR `band_name` <> ', $bands);
```

And also you have to make `()`aroud your `OR`statements

```
SELECT `band_name`, `band_id` 
FROM `song_genres` 
WHERE `band_name` != 'Bears and Company' AND (`genre` LIKE '%Indie Rock%' OR `genre` LIKE '%Progressive Rock%' OR `genre` LIKE '%Alternative Rock%' OR `genre` LIKE '%Indie Folk%')
```

Use prepared statements instead. It is much more safety and readable.

Comment: I also know the same thing that not equals in SQL is  `<>` but I checked the MySQL manual and it says this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal and I tried running a simple query `select 1 != 2` and it worked. So are there any specific conditions for both the operators?

Comment: It doesn't work. Mysql accepts both **<>** and **!=** to mean Not Equal to. Neither of them work sadly.

Comment: @Deep Maybe that is an mysql extention. Loook at my second hint.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tried all of the suggestions, but none of them worked. But I changed:

```
$bandString = implode(' OR `band_name` != ', $bands);
```

to this:

```
$bandString = implode(' AND `band_name` != ', $bands);
```

Apparently the OR condition caused the condition to skip over all the values. I simply wasn't paying attention when I wrote the statement.